# Behaviour of sendBroadcast

Tags: android, handler

I need to send some data to my service on app startup. I put data to `Intent`, cast `sendBroadcast(intent)` in `onCreate` method of my activity. So my service doesn't receive any intents.
But if i use `Handler.post` with custom `Runnable` in `onCreate` everything works fine.
Can someone explain me such a strange behavior?

Doesn't work at all:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    broadcastIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST);
    broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("URLs", alURLS);
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
}
```

Works perfectly:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    broadcastIntent = new Intent(BROADCAST);
    broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("URLs", alURLS);
    hDelayedPost = new Handler();
    hDelayedPost.post(rHandleDelayedSendBroadcast);
}

private Runnable rHandleDelayedSendBroadcast = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> So my service doesn't receive any intents

Services do not receive broadcasts. `BroadcastReceivers` receive broadcasts.

**UPDATE**: Presumably, your `Service` is not yet running in `onCreate()` of your activity, and you are calling `startService()` sometime between `onCreate()` and when your delayed `sendBroadcast()` is called.

Comment: Yes, that's what i actually meant.

Comment: @Outofdate: How are you registering your `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: In my Service overriden method `onCreate`:         `registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(MainActivity.BROADCAST));`

Comment: Is there better way to call sendbroadcast() right after my Service started?